# How do I fix "Error connecting to the service protocol" when I try debug on a real device

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I am getting "Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:51317/gj92Km4W51c=/
" when I try to debug my flutter project on a physical Android device from VS Code. The app launches and shows a black screen. I tried with 2 devices and they both worked fine the first time, but after that, they both started giving this error.

I am running on Windows 10, with latest Flutter. Flutter doctor shows no issues.

Running in an emulator works fine.

Running on the physical device from the command line, using `flutter run` works fine.

I have tried the following, which don't help:

- flutter clean
- restart VSCode
- uninstall app from device

**Restarting the device resolves the issue for 1 run and then it stops working again.**

Is there a more permanent solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47629) that was apparently resolved, but that I am still seeing with the latest version of Flutter.

Running `adb logcat -c` before starting the debugger works for me. Although this is not a fix, it is a lot less time consuming than restarting my device.

Comment: I love you man, it did worked after running it.